# conditional preg_match in PHP

Tags: php, regex, conditional-statements, preg-match

tried `/[^fF\d+\s+]?[AF]?[\s+]?(\d+(\.\d{1,2})?-\d+(\.\d{1,2})?)/`

want to match:

```
AF11-16 
AF 11-16
11-16
16.5-100
```

but do not match:

```
f3.5-5.6
F3.5-5.6
f 3.5-5.6
F 3.5-5.6
```

want to extract the focal length range as result, like 11-16

do not know how to use conditional subpattern, any idea? thx!

Comment: Explain the structural difference between match and don't want. It's difficult to devise an expression without understanding the desired pattern.

Comment: want to: 1. start with "af" or do not start with anything 2. pattern is "number(1 dec places)" then "-" then "number(1 dec places)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?:af)?\s?([\d.]+)-([\d.]+)$
```

This one works for your dataset, [as you can see here](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2ussv).

Comment: Well, no. At least, not on RegexPal.

Comment: This is almost correct. thx. but the result array returned differs when "af" is given or not. Have to check if the result start with "af" again. And can you explain the reg exp above?

Comment: @joetsuihk: For an explaination of the regex please use one of the following tools http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world

Comment: @joetsuihk PHP doc: "$matches[0] will contain the text that matched the full pattern, $matches[1] will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on."

Comment: @mario the quickrex do not support PHP reg? only Perl? @sexyprout can you please explain "(?:af)"?

Comment: can above altered to mis-match "abc f3.5-5.6"?

Comment: @joetsuihk `(?:blahblah)` is a non-capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
\d+
```

use

```
\d{2,}
```

which will matches two or more digits.

```
/[^fF\d+\s+]?[AF]?[\s+]?(\d{2,}(\.\d{1,2})?-\d{2,}(\.\d{1,2})?)/
```